# azure devops dashboard for multi-stage pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-dashboard

I create a multi-stage pipeline in YML file including build stage and deployment to dev, test and production.
I ant to have a dashboard to show me the status of deployment and which release version was deployed to each stages?
I check the "Deployment Status" widget, but it only work with release option.
So anybody has experience to support me?

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid that there are no out-of-the-box widgets to display the stages of the YAML pipeline and the status of each stage on the azure devops dashboard. Currently, the `Release Pipeline Overview` widget accomplishes this but it cannot be linked to a YAML pipeline.

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [ADO Dashboard Widget-Release Pipeline Overview should support YAML Pipelines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1015212/ado-dashboard-widget-release-pipeline-overview-sho.html). You can add your vote directly at the above linked feedback. Voting helps increase the priority of the suggestion by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps!

Here is a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1014475/ado-dashboard-widget-release-pipeline-overview-not.html) with similar issue.